# code is showing error : nan , is it related to np.nan or is it some other error?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-science

What is the error in this code is it due to the line df['SuperTrend'] = np.nan?

```
 def SuperT(df, f, n):
      df['Upper Basic'] = (df['High'] +df['Low'])/2 +(f*df['ATR'])
      df['Lower Basic'] = (df['High']+ df['Low'])/2 -(f*df['ATR'])
      df['Upper Band'] = df['Upper Basic']
      df['Lower Band'] = df['Lower Basic']
      for i in range(n ,len(df)):
        if df['Close'][i-1] <= df['Upper Band'][i-1]:
          df['Upper Band'][i] = min(df['Upper Basic'][i] , df['Upper Band'][i-1])
        else :
          df['Upper Band'][i] = df['Upper Basic'][i]  
      for i in range(n ,len(df)):
        if df['Close'][i-1] >= df['Lower Band'][i-1]:
          df['Lower Band'][i] = max(df['Lower Basic'][i] , df['Lower Band'][i-1])
        else :
          df['Lower Band'][i] = df['Lower Basic'][i] 
      df['SuperTrend'] =np.nan
      for i in df['SuperTrend']:
        if df['Close'][n-1]<= df['Upper Band'][n-1]:
          df['SuperTrend'][n-1] = df['Upper Band'][n-1]    
        elif df['Close'][n-1]>df['Upper Band'][i]:
          df['SuperTrend'][n-1]=df['Lower Band'][n-1]
      for i in range(n,len(df)):
        if df['SuperTrend'][i-1]==df['Upper Band'][i-1] and df['Close'][i]<=df['Upper Band'][i]:
          df['SuperTrend'][i]=df['Upper Band'][i]
        elif  df['SuperTrend'][i-1]==df['Upper Band'][i-1] and df['Close'][i]>=df['Upper Band'][i]:
          df['SuperTrend'][i]=df['Lower Band'][i]
        elif df['SuperTrend'][i-1]==df['Lower Band'][i-1] and df['Close'][i]>=df['Lower Band'][i]:
          df['SuperTrend'][i]=df['Lower Band'][i]
        elif df['SuperTrend'][i-1]==df['Lower Band'][i-1] and df['Close'][i]<=df['Lower Band'][i]:
          df['SuperTrend'][i]=df['Upper Band'][i]
        return
```

The function dont show an error on running but as soon as the function is called an error pops up.

Error:

```
KeyError: nan
```

Comment: And how do you call your function? Are all parameters provided in the function call? Are the provided parameters valid in the context of the function? What is the intention of the function? We don't know.

Comment: @Mr.T  this is a trading indicator function known as SuperTrend(https://www.tradingfuel.com/supertrend-indicator-formula-and-calculation/) 
df-Datset
f= Multiplier
n= period of days

Comment: @JonathanLeon I am not able to catch up . Can you please provide code.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted my comment after looking at this a little closer. Here's what I was trying to say about this for loop:

```
  df['SuperTrend'] =np.nan

  for i in df['SuperTrend']:
    if df['Close'][n-1]<= df['Upper Band'][n-1]:
      df['SuperTrend'][n-1] = df['Upper Band'][n-1]    
    elif df['Close'][n-1]>df['Upper Band'][i]:
      df['SuperTrend'][n-1]=df['Lower Band'][n-1]
```

All your other for loops start with
`for i in range(n ,len(df))`
so i is an integer

In the loop above, the only reference to i is `df['Upper Band'][i]`
Your code thinks i is np.nan as in `df['Upper Band'][nan]` because you are looping the values in the series. I believe the error is saying, there is no key (column or index) 'nan'

Comment: I understand your point & tried to apply it    `i = len(df['Close']) - 1` .The function worked upon calling but the SuperTrend column remained with nan values

Comment: Sorry, don't know enough about supertrend but you have two loops at the end working on that column. If all your data up to this point is correct it's just tedious trouble shooting your loops and if statements. Are you sure there isn't a technical analysis library that calculates this? Or are you customizing it?